# ¿Cómo relacionar los href con los botones del formulario?

Tags: php, mysqli

Muy buenas.
En un formulario, creé dos botones y he estado tratando de poner acciones con los demás páginas php que contienen los querys de MySqli procedural. Lo que no comprendo por los input type que creé para los demás botones, ya que al tratar de rellenar el formulario, elegiendo cada uno de los botones y solo tiene accion del mismo anadirimplode.php. Habrá alguna forma de que los demás botones puedan seguir con los acciones de otras páginas? Este es el código del php:

**pruebacafe2.php**

```html
<h1>Cafe</h1>
<form method="POST" action="anadirimplode.php">
<p><b>Selección de Cafe</b></p>
id_compra_cafe: <input type="text" name="id_compra_cafe"><br/>
Cafe:<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="1"/> Nescafe <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="2"/> Americano <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="3"/> Macciato <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="4"/> Doble <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="5"/> Cortado <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="6"/> Capuccino <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="7"/> Irlandes <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_cafe[]" value="8"/> Cafe Solo<br/>
Usuario: <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="1"/> Fslynx <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="2"/> Guts <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="3"/> Otter <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="4"/> Sebastian <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="5"/> Julian <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="id_usuario[]" value="6"/> Claire<br/> 
Precio: <input type="text" name="precio"><br>
IVA: <input type="text" name="iva"><br>
Total: <input type="text" name="total"><br>
<input type="submit" name="prueba" value="Enviar formulario">
<input type="reset" name="limpiar" value="Borrar formulario">
<input type="hidden" name="id_compra_cafe" value="<?php echo $_POST['id_compra_cafe']; ?>">
<form action="eliminacafe.php"><input type="submit" name="eliminar" value="Borrar Id"/>
<form action="editacafe.php"><input type="submit" name="editar" value="Editar Formulario"/>
</form>
</form>
</form>
```

Si notan por los dos botones de form action, eso es lo que he tratado para tener acción y relacionar con otras páginas php con MySqli Procedural. Estos son las otras páginas:

**eliminacafe.php**

```html
<?php 
$msg = $id_compra_cafe = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['eliminar'])){
 $id_compra_cafe = $_POST['id_compra_cafe'];

 if($id_compra_cafe){
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cafe");

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
   printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
  }

  $query = mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM compra_cafe WHERE id_compra_cafe = $_POST[id_compra_cafe]");

  if(!$query) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
  } else {
   $msg = "Registro borrado correcto";
  }
 }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

**editacafe.php**

```html
<?php 
$msg = $id_compra_cafe = $id_cafe = $id_usuario = $precio = $iva = $total = NULL;

if(isset($_POST['editar'])) {
 $id_compra_cafe = $_POST['id_compra_cafe'];
 $id_cafe = $_POST['id_cafe'][0];
 $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario'][0];
 $precio = $_POST['precio'];
 $iva = $_POST['iva'];
 $total = $_POST['total'];

 if($id_compra_cafe && $id_cafe && $id_usuario && $precio && $iva && $total){

  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cafe");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   printf("Fallo conexion: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
  }

  $query = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE compra_cafe SET precio='$precio', iva='$iva', total='$total' WHERE id_compra_cafe='$id_compra_cafe' AND id_cafe='$id_cafe' AND id_usuario='$id_usuario'");

  if(!$query) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
  } else {
   $msg = "Los datos estan editados";
  }
 }
}
echo $msg;
?>
```

Espero sus respuestas al respecto!
Saludos!

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que los inputs del primer form se usen en el segundo, directamente no se puede. Los elementos de un form solo aplican a ese form. Si los necesitas en otro form tendras que duplicarlos o usar javascript/jquery para crearlos dinamicamente en la llamada pero como minimo tendras que tener el boton que lance la accion..

Comment: @Lithorell, mucha razón. Practicamente podría hacer el formulario con solo dos botones, el enviar y limpiar formulario, por eso empieza la accion de uno de esos botones con el metodo del form. Muchas gracias por responder.

Comment: Cuidado con la inyección SQL. El código compartido contiene serias vulnerabilidades y problemas de seguridad.